# Will it be more computationally expensive to have multipl 2d tensors or 1 3d tensor

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, genetic-algorithms

Odd question but I am busy creating a Genetic Algorithm that optimizes the weights on a Neural Network instead of using good old fashion 1st-order optimization (Gradient/Adam)

What I have is x as a 2d vector (rows, columns)

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, total_input])
```

Since I need multiple neural networks instead of my hidden layer or output layer being 2d it needs to turn into a 3d vector.

```
fully_connected_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([size_in, size_out, total_networks], stddev=0.1), name="W")
acttivision1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input_tensor, w) + b)
```

I can now either have my next layer into multiple 2d vectors:

```
for neural_networks in layer1:
    fully_connected_2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1), name="W")
    activison2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(acttivision1 , w) + b)
```

or keep the 3d fashion.

```
fully_connected_2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([size_in, size_out,total_neural_networks], stddev=0.1), name="W")
activison2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(acttivision1 , w) + b)
```

As you have noticed the code is not 100% accurate as I am not even sure whether relu activision function will output a 3d vector.
I know it is going to be resource-intensive but the question is which one will be less computationally expensive. Also if you have a better idea please share. This is the only 2 solutions I can come up with.

Comment: Generally you are better packing all your data into one big tensor. At the worst TensorFlow will iterate over one dimension of the tensor and apply the operation to the rest. But when possible, TensorFlow will use more efficient algorithms. There might be specific cases where this rule isn't true but it should be assumed by default.

Comment: If I have time I will rapport back here with which option was the best solution. For now, I will try and stick to your advice, I have a deadline to meet so there is no time for experimentation.